# Angular UI - angular-google-maps. Is It possible to configure uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure(options) dinamically?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-ui, angular-promise

Is It possible to insert options dinamically from promise (ex. $http.get(...)) in to

```js
.config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure(<object from $http>);
})
```

of [angular-ui angular-google-maps](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/) directives?
If not could you suggest any alternative methods?

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, a service like [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) can not be injected into the *provider configuration section*. Instead you could consider the following solution:

- load configuration data
- once the data is loaded, configure Goolgle Maps loader via    `uiGmapGoogleMapApi` provider
- manually bootstrap the application

**Example**

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  $.getJSON('settings.json')
    .then(function (configData) {
      angular.module('myApp')
      .config(['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', function (uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
        uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure(configData);
       }]);
      angular.bootstrap('#myApp', ['myApp']);
    });
});
```

[**Demo**: plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/idh0OVLahwwhqUmUIKjx?p=preview)